Port forwarding refuses outside connection
I am trying to forward a port for my custom chat system, a project of mine. It has no problem when i try to access it from lan. However, if i try to access it from the router by calling telnet 192.168.1.1 25565 (my router ip) (also yes. it is on port 25565) it sends me rst back
the python script i'm using is this:
 import socket

# Create a socket object
server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

# Bind the socket to a specific address and port
server_socket.bind(("192.168.1.6", 25565))

# Listen for incoming connections
server_socket.listen(1)

print("Server started. Listening for incoming connections...")

while True:
    # Accept an incoming connection
    client_socket, address = server_socket.accept()
    print("Connected by", address)

    # Receive data from the client
    data = client_socket.recv(1024)
    print("Received data:", data.decode())

    # Send a response back to the client
    response = "Hello, client!".encode()
    client_socket.sendall(response)

    # Close the client socket
    client_socket.close()

A simple tool to check connection
How i tested my connection:
Opened server (started python script)
then form a command shell ran these commands
$telnet 192.168.1.6 25565
>>connected
$telnet 192.168.1.1 25565 (port    is forwarded from 192.168.1.6:25565 to *:25565)
>>telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
$telnet #myip 25565
>>no response
and here is the tcp trace
12:45:03.307761 IP ArchMachina.37048 > _gateway.25565: Flags [S], seq 656350756, win 32120, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 2166939235 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
12:45:03.308214 IP _gateway.25565 > ArchMachina.37048: Flags [R.], seq 0, ack 656350757, win 0, length 0
12:45:05.276699 IP ArchMachina.51468 > #myIp.25565: Flags [S], seq 2936786837, win 32120, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 3381757762 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
12:45:06.285348 IP ArchMachina.51468 > 8#myIp.25565: Flags [S], seq 2936786837, win 32120, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 3381758771 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
12:45:07.298667 IP ArchMachina.51468 > #myIp.25565: Flags [S], seq 2936786837, win 32120, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 3381759784 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0

there aren't any firewalls blocking this from my computer, and it doesn't seem like the router has any
I managed to do port forwarding like three months ago and then i didn't use it anymore. But i left it open (i know it's bad practice but yeah). Now when i wanted to do it again it doesn't work anymore. It drives me insane, because i can't seem to figure out the problem
I suspect there is something to do with the router, but i can't be sure

Connecting to internal router IP does not work because forwarding is for connection on external interface. Connecting to external IP from inside does not work because your router likely does not support NAT loopback - duplicate to NAT translation not working from inside the network (hairpin condition).

Good to know. But It says that port is closed when i check with port checker.

It might still be that you did not properly configure port forwarding. Unfortunately you show only the server code and your tests, but have no details about the configured port forwarding apart from that it used to work.

I don't know what happened. I didn't change anything from yesterday, but now it works for some mysterious reason
Port open
All i did today was run telnet on address 192.168.1.2 (the ip shown on my router
Router ip)
Life is fun.
